# Very low requests per second in my server over a network

Tags: c, performance, networking, optimization

I'm writing an HTTP/2 server which is currently progressing well. I'm now trying to optimize the server, so I did some benchmarks between it and nginx. When running the server locally, and running the benchmark tool (h2load) on the same machine, nginx gets about 2200 requests/second and my server gets about 1600 requests/second, which is about what I expected. I still have a lot of room for optimization.

However when I test over a network, i.e when the benchmark tool is run from a remote machine, nginx stays at about 1800 requests/second but my server drops down to about 90 requests/second. This indicates to me that there is a bottleneck in my handling of I/O as opposed to anywhere else. I did a bit of profiling with callgrind and gperftools but I can't see anything obvious that would be causing such a massive slowdown. I reckon it might be to do with the way I'm handling outgoing writes, as I'm writing about 4 small TLS records of 100-600 bytes each per request. I've also settled on using TCP_NODELAY because if I don't use it then it drops to a further 3 requests/second (and it drops to the same if I use TCP_CORK).

I have two questions:

1) How do I go about finding the bottlenecks that are causing the drop in performance?

2) Let's say that my poor buffering of outgoing writes was responsible for the majority of the slowdown here. What buffering strategies can I use to improve performance? It seems that either way I'd be stuck with the possibility of allocating far too much data than I actually need, or ending up reallocating far too many times, or scheduling outgoing writes poorly due to not being able to reorder data just before it's sent. Are there any resources which explain this in more detail?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/64/hh) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, congratulations and best of luck to your project, it certainly looks impressive.

Now: I predict your concurrency-socket engineering has an issue. I'm not heavily experienced with socket programming on a web-server level. However I know that Linux Sockets can be heavily optimized for any given situation. Sockets optimized used over localhost are not always optimized over networks (ie, TCP_CORK does wonders over localhost). Convulsively, certain socket configurations (and utilization) work best in multi-thread/multi-proc network systems.

I would suggest you go the the experts. I doubt you'll find one hanging out on StackOverflow.

- See the source code: https://github.com/nginx/nginx
- Contact people who've worked on it: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx (See 'Author' column)

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind words! I will accept this answer in a few hours, in case any one else wants to submit an answer in the meantime.